# Issue with malformed csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm trying to make it so i can read this and parse respectively. However I'm running into an issue.

This is the line I have:

```
csv = CSV.read(csvtoopen, :headers=>true, quote_char: '|', encoding: "bom|utf-8")
```

and this is the error I get:

```
CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 64704.
```

Any ideas how to get this working??

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quote char doesn't seem to be properly set. Try:

```
csv = CSV.read(csvtoopen, :headers=>true, quote_char: '"', encoding: "bom|utf-8")
```